# Nokogiri returning href attribute as nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am building a small API with just two endpoints (at least by now) defined in my config/routes.rb by:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get '/api/list',      to: 'api#list'
  get '/api/add/:url',  to: 'api#add'

end
```

One of the endpoints receives an URL and I parse and store some of its contents with the following code in app/controllers/api_controller.rb:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'httparty'

class ApiController < ApplicationController

  def list
  end

  def add
    @url = "http://#{params[:url]}"
    site = Site.create(url: @url)
    site.save!
    page = HTTParty.get(@url)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
    ['h1','h2','h3','a'].each do |tag|
      doc.xpath("//#{tag}").each do |cont|
        if (tag == 'a') then
          content = Content.create({site_id: site.id, text: cont.at_xpath('/a/@href').to_s.strip!, content_type: 'href', content_tag: tag })
        else 
          content = Content.create({site_id: site.id, text: cont.text().to_s.strip!, content_type: 'tag_content', content_tag: tag })
        end
        content.save!
      end
    end
  end

end
```

I managed to get the contents of `<h1>`, `<h2>` and `<h3>` tags perfectly, but the content of the `href` attributes for `<a>` tags is being saved as `nil` and I really don't know what is wrong with this:

```
cont.at_xpath('/a/@href').to_s.strip!
```

expression.

I already tried:

```
cont.at_xpath('/@href').to_s.strip!
```

since `cont` is already the `a` node in this case, but it happened the same.

I am using Rails 5 and I started my project with `--api`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the anchor tag first and then pass the href attribute.

You get the anchor tag already with this code:

```
['h1','h2','h3','a'].each do |tag|
  doc.xpath("//#{tag}").each do |cont|
  end
end
```

Now you only use `cont` that contains the anchor tag to get its href using `cont['href']`:

```
content = Content.create({site_id: site.id, text: cont['href'], content_type: 'href', content_tag: tag })
```

Comment: It continue not working. Still getting `nil` as the value of href attribute.

Comment: Yes, now it works. I didn't know it was possible to mention attributes of a node in this "hash-like" way. Thanks for your help!